# java BufferedReader & Writer doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

What I was trying to do was to read a mnist train file, and express it's first digit in eleven digits, and keep other same.

So 3,1,4,6 ... to  ,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,6... (there's "" at first digit so total 11 digits)

I thought it's an easy job but it wasn't.

```
import java.io.*;
public class T {
public static void main(String[] args){
    File file = new File("./src/dataset/mnist_train.csv");
    File wfile = new File("./src/dataset/conv_mnist_train2.txt");

    try{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(wfile));
        String line;
        String[] numbers;
        int g = 0, cnt = 0, cnt2 = 0;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            cnt2++;
            numbers = line.split(",");
            for(String i : numbers){
                if(g == 0){
                    for(int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
                        if(j == Integer.parseInt(i)) fileWriter.write("," + 1);
                        else{ fileWriter.write("," + 0); cnt++;}
                    }
                    g++;
                }
                else {fileWriter.write("," +i); cnt++;}
            }
            fileWriter.newLine();

            System.out.println(numbers.length + " " + cnt + " " + cnt2);
            g = 0; cnt = 0;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

g, cnt, cnt2 are numbers I used for debugging but I didn't find any problem here; it naturally converted each lines with 785 letters into new lines with 795 letters.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Tes {
public static void main(String[] args){
    File file = new File("./src/dataset/conv_mnist_train2.txt");

    try{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int g = 0;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            g++;
            String[] N = line.split(",");
            if(N.length != 795){
                System.out.println(N.length + " " + g);
                for(String i : N) System.out.print(i + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

But what happened is that when I run my second code, which shouldn't print anything, printed result and said my 59994th row data is only consisted of 311 letters. But from my first code, I confirmed that my 59994th row has 795 letters. I don't know what's going on here.

Also I tried to use FileWriter and FileReader instead of BufferedWriter & Reader, but it didn't solve problem. Could somebody tell me what's going on, and how to fix this?

Comment: You never close your readers and your writers. Learn to use the try-with-resources statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: thank you. I didn't know not closing reader/writer could end up in serious consequences like this.

Comment: A buffered writer, by definition, buffers what you write to it in memory. It writes to the file when the buffer is full, or when you close (or flush) it. If you never close, you miss parts of the file. Resources must always be closed anyway, because they're scarce. If you forget to close hundreds of file resources, your OS won't have enough file descriptors available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't close the reader/writer. Didn't know it could end up in serious error.